# Macro terminates inside the code without error

Tags: vba, ms-word

After the new document is created (documents.add), the macro pass ends.

I tried the documents.add with parameter (visible:=false) but no effect.

```
Sub beispiel()

    Dim objDokQuelle As Document
    Dim objDokZiel As Document

    On Error GoTo FEHLER

    Set objDokQuelle = ActiveDocument
    Set objDokZiel = Documents.Add    'This is the last line to be processed; then the macro terminates

    'The following lines are not processed
    objDokQuelle.Activate
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Copy
    objDokZiel.Activate
    Selection.Paste

FEHLER:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error ..."
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't understand what is wrong in this Code, so the macro terminates at the commented line. There are no error Messages.
Thanks for help.

Comment: The code you post works fine on my PC.  Try commenting out the on error line so see if you get an error reported.  You should also insert a Exit Sub after the selection past so that you don't inadvertently execute your error code.

Comment: Hi Freeflow, if I comment out the line, the Code works fine. ;-( I suspect our corporate IT has manipulated the documents.add to use it for home-wide document templates. Is this possible? Also another macro that has been working reliably with documents.add for years no longer works.

Comment: Quit Word. Hold down the Ctrl key while starting Word back up - this puts Word in "Safe Mode" (installation defaults, most especially, no add-ins will load). Open the file that contains the macro and try again. Does it run?

Comment: It is possible.  If they have its likely it  will be by providing a substitute for 'DocumentActionsPane' so you could search your available templates to see if that is the case.  Reading this may help  https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrint.htm

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers. I spoke to someone from the company IT who could give me a registry key to load the template or not. Meanwhile, the macro also runs when the template is loaded. I'm confused. Thanks again. The question is solved.

Comment: Probably not related to the problem, but add `Exit Sub` just before your `FEHLER:` label - error handling should be outside the main body of code.